# Concatenation two data from two fetch in react native

Tags: react-native, concatenation

I am sorry for distributing you with stupid question,i have to make notification page ,where i know sender and notification's data,
but i cant concatenated sender and notification's data

```
 let responseJson = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJson)
        if(responseJson.success){
            // this.setState(this.state.data.sender=responseJson.data.sender)
          responseJson.data.map(notificationInfo=>{

            this.getData(notificationInfo.id,notificationInfo.sender)

        })
        }
        else{
            console.log("No notification")
        }
```

Method getdata

```
..FETCH
 const responseJson = await response.json();
            this.setState({data:responseJson})
            // console.log(responseJson.success)
            if(typeof responseJson.success != "undefined"){
                this.setState({
                    data=[...this.state.data,sender]
            })
```

the best answer was like below:

```
Array [
  Object {//sender
    "name": "Admin Adminovich",
     #someother data


  },
  Object {   
    "name": "Test Testovich",
     #someother data
  },
  Object {
    "name": "just4ina",
    #someother data
  },
```

but I need it like

```
data:[
  Object {   
    "name": "Test Testovich",
     "sender": Object {//sender
    "name": "Admin Adminovich",
     #someother data
  },
  Object {   
    "name": "Test",
     "sender": Object {//sender
    "name": "Admin Adminovich",
     #someother data
  },
]
```

ALL concatenation was not what i want

Comment: What is `this.state.data` ?

Comment: it is where i wanted to save all data

Comment: Oh, I said it wrong. He was referring to the price of responseJson.